# Creating automatically shifting time series with maximum number of entries

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to extract values from an Excel worksheet (Sheet1) and save them into Sheet2 every minute, automatically creating a new row each minute.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Call CopyValues

End Sub

Sub CopyValues()
Dim RowNo As Long
RowNo = Sheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 2)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 3)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 4) = Sheets(1).Cells(14, 4)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 5) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 2)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 6) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 3)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(15, 4)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 2)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 9) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 3)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 10) = Sheets(1).Cells(16, 4)
    Sheets(4).Cells(RowNo, 11) = Sheets(1).Cells(17, 2)

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CopyValues"

End Sub
```

What I can't figure out is how to do the following: after 24 hours has passed and I have 24x60 = 1440 rows of data, for every subsequent minute I'd like to delete the first row of data, shift all the data below this up by one row (so for example row 2 goes back to the now empty row 1, row 3 goes into row 2, up to row 1440). I would also want to bring the new data in at the last row. This way there is only ever a maximum of 1440 rows of data on the sheet.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Hi @pottolom, how about using an IF statement, where if RowNo > 1440, then delete the first row and set the values in `Sheets(4).Cells(1440, ...` etc? After 24 hours it would always execute this path

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure how that would work. If I delete the first row, how would I ensure the other rows shift upwards by one row each.

Comment: If you delete the entire row it will shift all rows below up be 1 by default, you can also specify the shift parameter. `Rows(1:1).Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 0):

maxhob17's answer seems to have worked.

I simply added the following code before Application.OnTime in the code above:

```
If RowNo > 1440 Then
    Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
```

To clarify, I delete the second row rather than the first, as my headers are in the first.